# Filtering data Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#

I have written code to sort a `.csv` file. What I need now is to read just rows with ordered value and write them to datagridview. For example read just rows where value of Age is 22. the file looks like:

```
 ID Name Surname Age Salary
 -------------------------- 
 1  John Asben   33  1000
 2  Adam Smith   22  1200
 3  Amanda J     22  2000
 4  George Villis 36  2300
```

My problem is in filtering data, for example when I click button show Employee by age and for type 22 for Age the program has to show in datagridview just records (rows) where value for column age is 22. I tried a code but it shows the error:

> Input string was not in a correct format

I think because the first row data type is different from other rows.

My code looks like this:

```
private void btnAge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        List<string[]> parsedData = ReadAndSelectdata(@"C:\sorteddata.csv", ',');

        int age;

        if (txtage.Text != "")
        {
            age = int.Parse(txtage.Text);
            DrawDataGridView(parsedData.Where(p => (p[3] == "Age") || (int.Parse(p[3]) == age)).ToList());
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Please type the age for Employee");
}
```

Comment: why do you need a list of string array? you could use a List of employee

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should create a class called Employee

```
    class Employee
    {
       public int ID {get;set;}
       public string Name {get;set;}
       public string Surname {get;set;}
       public int Age {get;set;}
       public int Salary {get;set;}
     }
```

Change the ReadAndSelectData method to return a `List<Employee>`
and then all you need to do is

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtage.Text))
{
   DrawDataGridView(parsedData.Where(p=>p.Age == int.parse(txtage.Text));
}
else
{.....}
```